# close bootstrap modal dialog on mouseout

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I want to close Modal Popup on mouseout. I wrote a code to modal popup on mouse hover. But not able to write close Modal on mouseout.

Below is the code for Mouse hover Modal Popup appears. But need to close on mouse out.

```js
<script>
$("#b1").hover(function () {
    $('.bs-example-modal-lg').modal({
        show: true,
        backdrop: false
    }); 
});

</script>
```

```html
<div class="slide" data-thumb="../thumbs/Q50_thumb.jpg">
             
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" title="">
<img src="../original/Q50_v1_large.jpg" alt="">
<p style="text-align:center;"><i class="icon-line-bag"></i> Hover to details</p>
</a>
            </div>
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
 <div class="modal-body">
   <p>Press the SOS button for 3 seconds, user&nbsp;can call and send alarm messages to the phone number.</p>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass a second param to hover which is a function too and hide the overlay of the popup.:

```
$("#b1").hover(function () {
    $('.bs-example-modal-lg').modal({
        show: true,
        backdrop: false
    }); 
}, function () {
   $('.bs-example-modal-lg').modal('hide);  
});
```

Comment: I would have recommended using .mouseout(). But this is even better!

Comment: I applied your code but now Modal Box appear and hide on mouse click. I need to on mouseover appear and mouseout disapper. Any other suggestion. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Change the show function with: `$('.bs-example-modal-lg').modal('show');`

Comment: See here example here: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4556/  on mouse hover working perfect but i need close modal on mouseout.

Comment: I update your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/owzhjfdx/. I mentionned **hide the overlay of the popup**